# AVAudioPlayer didn't run from url file in Swift Programming

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, nsurl

I am very new to Swift programming and has started learning a few weeks now. I am testing a AVAudioPlayer from YouTube tutorials and it works perfectly. Here is the code.

```
let filelocation  = NSString( string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.navigationItem.title, ofType: "mp3")!)
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL( fileURLWithPath: filelocation as String)!, error: &error)
```

Those mp3 files are placed in the project so it is playing locally. I changed the code to the following to get mp3 file from URL and played it here. But it didn't work.

```
let url : NSString = "https://ia601409.us.archive.org/20/items/UsaNationalAnthemFromSilo/silosinging-us-anthem_64kb.mp3"
let urlStr : NSString = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL( fileURLWithPath: urlStr as String)!, error: &error)
```

I got an error at player.prepareToPlay()  with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and value is "error NSError?    domain: "NSOSStatusErrorDomain" - code: 2003334207  0x00007fc3e3e4b820"

I am thinking NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr as String)! is not correct, so it is giving just nil. Any thoughts on how to correct it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use NSURL(fileURLWithPath:) method to create a url from a web link.  When creating url from links you need to use NSURL(string:) but you should download your data asynchronously using dataTaskWithUrl as follow:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player:AVAudioPlayer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let link = "https://ia601409.us.archive.org/20/items/UsaNationalAnthemFromSilo/silosinging-us-anthem_64kb.mp3"
        if let linkUrl = NSURL(string: link) {
            println(linkUrl)
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(linkUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    println("Finished downloading")
                    // you can use the data! here
                    if let data = data {
                        var error:NSError?
                        self.player = AVAudioPlayer(data: data, error: &error)
                        if let error = error {
                            println(error.description)
                        } else {
                            self.player.prepareToPlay()
                            self.player.play()
                        }
                        // there is data. do this
                    } else if let error = error {
                        println(error.description)
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed to this but still didn't work.  player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!, error: &error)

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem if you use NSURL(string:) see my edit

Comment: I just tested your link and it downloaded the data fine as you can see the file length  "935937"

Comment: Thanks. Yes...I run your code as you mentioned above. I saw the file length output. But again the error still stop at player = AVAudioPlayer(....) line.

Comment: The same error fatal error: 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81139/discussion-between-zhtway-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: try changing AVAudioPlayer(data: data, error: &error) and access the downloaded data instead of loading from the url. see my edit

Comment: I will post a async method for you also

Answer (score 0):

You have to pre load the mp3 first, you can try this:

```
var p: AVAudioPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var errorPointer: NSErrorPointer = NSErrorPointer()
        var url = NSURL(string: "https://ia601409.us.archive.org/20/items/UsaNationalAnthemFromSilo/silosinging-us-anthem_64kb.mp3")
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
        let conf: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSession.sharedSession().configuration
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: conf)
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println("\(error)")
            }else {
                self.p = AVAudioPlayer(data: data, error: errorPointer)
            }
            }.resume()

    }
```

and then in an action do this:

```
@IBAction func pushButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        p!.prepareToPlay()
        p!.volume = 100
        p!.play()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested you code too. It is the same as Leo's code but yours is slower downloading and start playing the file.